# remove link from the l() function in drupal after the first click

Tags: php, drupal

How does one remove the hyperlink from the l() function after the first click. A working example would be helpful.
 My link is of the form 

  `l(25,$_GET['q'],array('query'=>array("itemcount"=>"25")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JQuery Plugin called [one_time_action](http://www.headjump.de/article/jquery-plugin-one_time_action) to implement this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You...don't use the l() function then? It's for creating a link.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is best for doing stuff like this. Doing it with PHP wouldn't be impossible, just foolish. You'd have to write your own version of l() that keeps track of the click count with session/global variables or worse...